# Access Amazon EC2 Root

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to install `ZPanel` on my `AMAZON EC2` but it required root access.

I am new at Amazon EC2, and I have recently configured PHP-MySQL through `ec2-user`, but when I am going to use `root` instead of `ec2-user`, its not working.

Any ideas how I could access root?

Comment: This question doesn't belong here. It is not programming related. Try [Super User](http://www.superuser.com) instead

Comment: You use username `root`? Isn't the root username `ubuntu`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get root access using sudo. Commands are in this form `sudo <command>` or you can access an elevated shell using `sudo su`